# upgrade golang to 1.1.5 in vscode not showing

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

My os is windows 10 on which I have installed golang 1.16 and the version of golang on my vscode is 1.13 but since I am using my laptop for work, I have been asked to upgrade from 1.13 to 1.15

I did the following steps in terminal of vscode-ubuntu

```
$ sudo wget https://golang.org/dl/go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz

$ sudo tar -C /usr/local -xzf go1.15.5.linux-amd64.tar.gz

$ export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin

$ source ~/.bashrc

$ go version
```

still it shows version 1.13

Comment: Why you are using vscode-ubuntu if your system is window?

Comment: What output is for `which go` ?

Comment: Unless `/usr/local/go/bin` is mentioned in your .bashrc, you're overwriting the PATH by sourcing it. If Go 1.13 is installed elsewhere it make take precedence because it appears earlier in PATH. And don't use sudo for wget!

Comment: Thank you all, earlier versions of installed go was creating a conflict with dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled vscode,ubuntu and wsl as the cache kept holding onto previous installations of go.
Now it correctly shows go 15 at the bottom of the vscode window.
I typed 'which-a go'
now it shows usr/local/go/bin/go
Now the issue has been resolved.Thanks again.